# App Indexing- app not showing with website link in google search

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing, google-search-platform

I have integrated App Indexing and i tested my implementation by
[Link Testing in Android Studio](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/test#link-testing-in-android-studio) , [Android Debug Bridge](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/test#android-debug-bridge) and [Deep link testing tool](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/test#deep-link-testing-tool) . In all three tests I am able to open the app . But still when i do search in google I am NOT able to see my app with website link like below image.However if app is installed in device I am able to see app in choice of search autocompletion.I have not published the updated version of app in play store.Is that the reason i can't see app with website link?I am confused whether App Indexing is correctly impemented.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The app must be published on Google Play. Then you can use [Preview your APK on Search Console](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/test#preview-your-apk-on-search-console).
Also, [Declare a website association](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app#declare-a-website-association). After you make association, Google automatically starts indexing any existing or new URLs to your app.

Cheers,

MB